# L200 regulator power supply circuit design help!

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, linear-regulator

So here is the thing, I'm far from an expert in electronics, I'am pretty good with following a schematic but not designing one.

I have made a power supply based of the LM317 that worked out pretty well. But now I wanna try it out with the L200 regulator. The problem that I have is that there is no simulating model for the L200 (Using Multisim). And if I can't simulate the circuit I have a hard time testing different stuff.

So I would really appreciate if anyone have some time over and could draw me a circuit that will fulfill my purposes.

[L200 Datsheet](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Power/l200.pdf) & [L200 Designers Guide](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/10/b7/90/4a/dc/9d/4d/bb/CD00003773.pdf/files/CD00003773.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003773.pdf)

PSU requirements:

Voltage adjustment: 2.8V - 30V.

Current Adjustment: 10mA - 5A

The hard part:

I want to make the current go through a 2N3055 power transistor, the datasheets does not say how I can make both voltage/current adjustment + using an NPN transistor.
I have pretty much infinite space to build the power supply in so I can fit in a BIIIG heatsink without any problems.

Comment: "And if i can't simulate the circuit i have a hard time testing different stuff. " that is where the engineers have their formulas and breadboards for

Comment: I know and i do have a breadboard, But with simulation you can't "blow anything up" :P

Comment: otoh with simulations you can be far away from reality and rely on a tool instead of gathering real experience.

Comment: That's true. it's just a habit to use simulation, then breadboard and then PCB.

Comment: I think rarely these days do I find systems that I could simulate as a whole. Might be that you are limiting yourself too much to things that can be simulated, there is a whole new and bigger world waiting to be discovered.

Comment: Well maybe i just got lucky, with the LM317 PSU i made i pretty much relied on simulation, if something worked in simulation i thought that it would work in real life (and it did with that circuit). but i know that the reality is different.